# Help showing this function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(A,d_{A})$, $(B,d_{B})$ be two metric spaces and let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a continuous function.
I am trying to show that the function $g: (A,d_{A}) \rightarrow (A \times B, d_{\max})$ given by
$g(x) = (x, f(x))$ is also continuous.

Since $f$ is continuous, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that if $d_{A}(x,y) < \delta$ then
$d_{B}(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$.

Now, $$d_{\max}(g(x), g(y)) = d_{\max}((x,f(x)), (y,f(y))) = \max{\left\{d_{A}(x,y), d_{B}(f(x), f(y))\right\}} < \max{\left\{\epsilon, \delta\right\}}$$
So if $\delta \leq \epsilon$ then $g$ is continuous, but what about if $\delta > \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous at $x$ you have that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0 : d_A(x,y)<\delta \implies d_B(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon.$$ Assume that $0<\delta'<\delta.$ Is not true that

$$d_A(x,y)<\delta' \implies d_B(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon?$$ So, in your proof you can always assume $\delta \le \epsilon.$